# Is it acceptable to vote to migrate a question and also answer it?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration

I never saw any discussion on it in meta - but it seems common knowledge that it is unacceptable to both vote to close a question and also answer it.

What about questions that should be migrated?

If a user asks a software question in SO, and I voted to migrate it to SU, is it acceptable if I also propose an answer to it, in SO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, while some people don't like it when people put answers on dupes, it's certainly not the consensus.
For migration, there's no controversy, just go ahead and give a good answer, and it will migrate with the question over to the other site.